# I am not getting response from ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am getting no response from ajax request . i am posting a ajax call to processor.php file and the processor.php file is processing the file and sending the processed file back to javascript i am gerring my result in my console log but it is not showing in the html.
My javascript code is :

```
function add_to_cart(item_name,item_price){
  $('.user-info').slideUp('1200');
  $('.cart-status').slideDown('1200');

  var dataString = "item_name=" + item_name + "&item_price=" + item_price + "&page=add_to_cart";
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/processor/processor.php",
    data:dataString,
    beforeSend:function(){
      $(".cart-show-product").html('<h3>Your Cart Status</h3><img src="images/loading.gif" align="absmiddle" alt="Loading...." class="center" /><br><p class="center">Please Wait...</p>');
    },
    success: function(response){
      console.log(response);
      $(".cart-show-products").html(response);
    }
  });
}
```

and my php is :

```
if(isset($_POST['item_name']) && !empty($_POST['item_name']) && isset($_POST['item_price']) && !empty($_POST['item_price']))
{
  $sql = mysqli_query($conn, 
      'SELECT * FROM 
        products_added 
        where 
        username = "'.mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).'" 
        and 
        item_added="'.mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['item_name']).'"'
);
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) < 1)
{
  mysqli_query($conn, 
        "INSERT INTO products_added values(
          '', 
          '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])."', 
          '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['item_name'])."', 
          '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['item_price'])."', 
          '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, '1')."', 
          '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['item_price'])."'
          '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, date("d-m-Y"))."')"
  );
?>
<table class="cart-show-products">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Sl.No</td>
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Qty</td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
<?php
  $sl_no = 1;
  $sql = mysqli_query(
          $conn, 
          'SELECT sum(amount) as grandtotal
                FROM products_added
                WHERE username = "'.mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).'"
                ORDER BY id'
  );
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
  $grandtotal = strip_tags($row['grandtotal']);
  $sql = mysqli_query(
                $conn, 
                'SELECT 
                id,
                item_added,
                price,
                quantity
                FROM products_added
                WHERE username = "'.mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).'"
                ORDER BY id'
  );
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
  $item_id = strip_tags($row['item_id']);
  $item_name = strip_tags($row['item_added']);
  $item_price = strip_tags($row['price']);
  $quantity = strip_tags($row['price']);
  ?>
    <tr class="items_wrap items_wrap<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
      <td><?php echo $sl_no++; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $item_name ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $quantity ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $item_price ?></td>
      <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove-from-cart" onclick="remove_this_item('<?php echo $item_id; ?>')"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Is there an element on your html page with class `cart-show-products`?  I see it in your PHP ajax page, if your php page is sending it back to your ajax script, then it's not on the page yet.

Comment: yes `cart-show-products` exists

Comment: is the url correct in ajax script ? The server side is working properly?

Comment: @Giannis yes correct...yapp working properly...i am getting response in the console

Comment: Waiiiit. I see that you have .cart-show-products in the response from the php script ? So how did you imagine to update something in DOM that arrived trough your ajax call ? You will need to bind it on success method to be able to do that

Comment: You obviously have a problem that we can't see because you haven't shown us the html that you want data inserted into. Check lenght of `$(".cart-show-products")` Also if it is a `<table>` you can't insert a `<table>` directly into a table. Are you sure that setting html in  `$(".cart-show-product")` doesn't remove your target?

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting a response in the console, then the issue must be with your HTML.  I think part of the problem is you've created a section on the HTML page wiht a class that is the same as the table the AJAX call is bringing into the page.  I would suggest changing the HTML element to us an ID instead. Something like

```
<div id="products-table"></div>
```

And then change your JavaScript to

```
function add_to_cart(item_name,item_price){
  $('.user-info').slideUp('1200');
  $('.cart-status').slideDown('1200');

  var dataString = "item_name=" + item_name + "&item_price=" + item_price + "&page=add_to_cart";
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/processor/processor.php",
    data:dataString,
    beforeSend:function(){
      $("#products-table").html('<h3>Your Cart Status</h3><img src="images/loading.gif" align="absmiddle" alt="Loading...." class="center" /><br><p class="center">Please Wait...</p>');
    },
    success: function(response){
      console.log(response);
      $("#products-table").html(response);
    }
  });
}
```

If you stay with the class names you've used, subsequent updates are going to have problems because you'll have 2 elements on the page with the same class. Your script could potentially be confused about which one to change.

Comment: @hasan, perhaps you need to post the html you're getting back from your ajax call.  Also, as suggested before, posting your HTML markup may be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

If this is your actual code, then you have a syntax error in your `PHP` file. There are a missing close bracket for:

```
if(isset($_POST['item_name']) && !empty($_POST['item_name']) && isset($_POST['item_price']) && !empty($_POST['item_price']))
```

The second problem is, you are not print anything, if this condition has failed.

**Note**

You do not need to use `isset`, if you are checking `empty`. `empty` will return false, if the variable not set.

You can debug your respons by check NET tab in your web developer tools, or see, what is the response of the AJAX.